# Scanning for Google Cast devices

Tags: ios, chromecast, google-cast

I have no Chromecast so I'm trying to use these apps as Google cast devices (receivers):

1. https://github.com/dz0ny/leapcast
2. https://itunes.apple.com/sk/app/rplay/id692511073?mt=8
3. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cr-cast/acmfmindblghbicdipoakcolegkcddbk

All of these apps worked fine (at least was found) with iOS YouTube application.

When I'm trying to find these "devices" (receivers) in my app with

```
self.deviceScanner = [GCKDeviceScanner new];
[self.deviceScanner addListener:self];
[self.deviceScanner startScan];
```

none device is found. No `GCKDeviceFilter` is used, I just want to see all cast devices on network. I'm using `GoogleCastFramework-2.2.1-Release`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

None of these app will be discovered, nor will work with the official Cast SDK since these are fake  (i.e. unofficial) devices. The official Cast SDK checks to make sure the Cast device is a genuine one.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to develop and test "sender" without Chromecast device? Is there some Chromeast emulator that I can run on Mac and can be found with official SDK.

Comment: No, there is no emulator; you need to get a device.